# 404 error when moving ajax request outside of document.ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can anyone tell me why that code does not work.

This the `js` code in the first jquery mobile page:

```
function finish() {
          var selectedRowsVal = [];
          jQuery("input:checked").each(function(){
                selectedRowsVal.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });
          if(selectedRowsVal.length === 0){
            alert(111);
          }else{alert(selectedRowsVal.length);
             jQuery.ajax({
                url: "../Login", 
                data: {selectedRows: 1},
                method: 'post',
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
                },
                success: function(data){}
            });
          }
        }
```

And this is the calling of finish function in another jQuery mobile page:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar" dir="rtl">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="finish();" data-role="button">finsh</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-role="button">send to many</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-role="button">send</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
```

the error shown up from ajax callback is `404 not found`, when i put the code of jQuery.ajax in jQuery(document).ready of the first page (index page) it works fine .

Comment: Error 404 indicates your url ("../Login") cannot be found.

Comment: @rontornambe i knew that but, as i said in the question: when i make the call from the jquery(document).ready in the same jquery mobile first page it works fine,when i move the jquery.ajax to anywhere  outside the onReady function it fails

Comment: You are using relative positioning "../", so could it be an incorrect file reference. You can test this hypothesis by fully qualifying the url and performing your tests.

Comment: Why would you have an ajax request outside of your document ready? That kinda defeats the purpose of ajax.

Comment: @rontornambe "../" is working fine i tested it extensively and i'm sure that's ok

Comment: @Francis i am a beginer in jquery & jquery mobile,when i write document ready function in any page rather than the first page the code does not executed,and in the same time the button (in the second page) who makes the ajax request not visible to the first page document ready

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will fix your problem but as far as I know there is not an option called `method` for the `$.ajax()` function. There is however a `type` option which should be set as you have `method` set in your code:

```
         jQuery.ajax({
            url     : "../Login", 
            data    : { selectedRows: 1 },
            type    : 'post',
            error   : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
            },
            success : function(data){}
        });
```

From the documentation:

> type
>
> Default: 'GET'
>
> The type of request to make ("POST" or
> "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as
> PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by
> all browsers.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/*